# i cant find that and i need help :((

Tags: part-identification

[image]

mảnh cần tìm là cái được khoanh đỏ như trong hình.mong được các bạn giúp đỡ tìm và nơi mua chúng

Comment: Hi Quân, and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please note that Bricks.SE is an English-exclusive site, can you edit your question with a translation? It does not need to be perfect, we'll gladly polish it if needed - but it needs to be in English at the first place.

Answer (score 2):

That is [Wedge, Plate 2 x 2 Pentagonal with Center Stud and 1 x 1/2 Raised Tab on Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=27928#T=C) (27928).

[image]

However, BrickLink does not show that it has been released in that color. From the little bit of the image shown I guess that it is from a render instead of a physical model and that the designer chose a part and color combination that might not exist.

Comment: I've spent a lot of time looking for it and I'm lucky to have your help, thank you very much

Comment: @Quân, please check out the [help] page, specifically the following article: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).